# Как заменить неизвестные символы в запросе http-адреса через request в python?

Tags: python, http, request

При парсинге на python мне надо получить доступ к странице сайта типа:

https://zachestnyibiznes.ru/company/ul/1027700229193_7736207543_OOO-YaNDEKS

Эта левая часть стандартная: https://zachestnyibiznes.ru/company/ul/

далее известна будет только эта часть адреса: _7736207543

а то, что до нее и после неизвестно ни по длине ни по содержанию. Есть ли возможность при get запросе из библиотеки request как-то решить это - наложить маску, указать звездочки и пр.?

```
path = https://zachestnyibiznes.ru/company/ul/1027700229193_7736207543_OOO-YaNDEKS
```

response = requests.get(path)

Comment: указывайте звёздочки, либо то, что поймёт данный конкретный http-сервер. скорее всего ничего он не поймёт, потому что никакими стандартами этого не требуется. так что если хотите звёздочек, или каких-нибудь иных метасимволов, запускайте собственный http-сервер, который будет на них реагировать так, как вам надо. это самый надёжный путь.

Comment: Если известна только часть, тогда делайте запрос через поиск на сайте, а не запрос страницы. Вот я вбил ИНН в строку поиска, открылась страница с результатами поиска и таким адресом: https://zachestnyibiznes.ru/search?query=7736207543 . Вот в ней находите список найденных результатов, переходите по ссылке, и там уже парсите.

Comment: Мне это надо для парсинга страниц с определенного сайта, поэтому про "запускать свой собственный сервер" я ничего не понял. А вот если я передаю адрес как: zachestnyibiznes.ru/search?query=7736207543 то правильного ответа не получаю - сервер или блокирует как-то или куда перенаправляет - не могу пока разобраться. Поэтому пытаюсь разобраться как можно открыть определенную страницу, в который не все символы известны